# Proof of block matrix ($2^k \times 2^k$) multiplication via induction over $k$

Tags: matrices

Given are $(n \times n)$ matrices $A$ and $B$, where $n=2^k$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$. We split $A$ and $B$ intro equal size quadrants (of size $n/2 \times n/2$) denoted by $A_{ij}$ with $i,j \in \{1,2\}$.

It is then well known that their product $C = A B$ can be calculated with a divide and conquer strategy such that $C_{ij} = A_{i1}B_{1j} + A_{i2}B_{2j}$.

I am to show that this property of $C_{ij}$ holds via induction over $k$ (not $n$).

My attempt was to decompose $A$ and $B$ into four separate matrices $A'_{ij}$, $B'_{ij}$,  of size $n \times n$ (such that each of them is 75% zeroed), then use the distributive law (we're allowed to use it) to get $AB = A'_{11}B'_{11}+ A'_{12}B'_{11}+ ... A'_{22}B'_{22}$.

I then argue that of these 16 products, 8 must be zero, and the others make of the result $C$ in the manner we want to show.

However, I'm having trouble with writing this down formally while staying brief. It would be very nice if you could show me how to prove this correctly.

Comment: If we have size $2^{k+1}\ x\ 2^{k+1}$, we can split it into four matrices with size $2^k\ x\ 2^k$, for which the formula holds because of the induction hypothesis. Using also the formula for $2\cdot 2$ blocks, the proof should be straight forward. Try it and show where you got stuck.

Comment: @Peter It was difficult to clearly prove that in the sum of 16 products, 8 must be zero. I argue that this derives directly from the definition of the naive matrix product, but there is probably a better way. It was also difficult to show that the resulting $C_{ij}$ consist of exactly the required parts of A and B (i.e. I could not show that the result of each product goes in the right place in $C$).

Comment: (I slightly edited the question to remove a mind lapse)